# Difference between Yoeman generators for aspnet and aspnet-angular

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, node.js, asp.net-core, yeoman

When I install generators for Yeoman, I usually go like this.

> npm install --global generator-aspnet

However, as I was playing with the embedded menu system of Yeoman, I noticed that it also lists other templates for *aspnet*. One of them is *aspnet-angular*. I went to the [webpage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnet-angular) of it but it was less than verbose so I learned almost nothing there.

What is the difference between the two generators: *generator-aspnet* and *generator-aspnet-angular* exactly? Is there really any difference (compared to going with the first one and adding Angular package manually by NPM)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice thing on the open source stuff is you can see access the source code.

Following the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/lidia-freitas/generator-aspnet-angular) in the linked NPM package, you can see in the `generators/app/templates/Controller/AboutController.cs` [file](https://github.com/lidia-freitas/generator-aspnet-angular/blob/master/generators/app/templates/Controllers/AboutController.cs#L4-L5) following lines

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

Which tells us, it's a generator for the legacy ASP.NET MVC (up to MVC 5), because the `System.Web.*` namespaces have been completely removed from ASP.NET Core, since they had a tight coupling to IIS which would prevented ASP.NET Core to become portable and run w/o IIS.

Comment: Awesome. That's a real gotcha, then. Angular-part in the name implied something **new** and more **open sourcy** whereas it actually was sticking to the old stuff. I suspected something was off when I got errors because during the installation it didn't find *APP_DATA*. It was fishy and now you confirmed it. Cool! It's actually the biggest issue I have with the front-end/open-source - too much stuff that for me (as an ignorant dev) looks equivalently reliable but for a you (as a seasoned savvy bloke) it's obvious.

Comment: In fact, as we're on the subject - you're welcome to take a peek at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574407/why-does-bootstrap-under-asp-net-core-install-razor). I recognize your nickname and recall that you've got a lot of helpful and insightful contributions in your past, hehe.