# Why does Bootstrap under ASP.NET Core install Razor?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, razor, asp.net-core

I've deployed a Core website generated by Yeoman (*yo aspnet*) and when asked what to put in as a GUI manager I had two choices - Bootstrap and Semantic. I went with Bootstrap and everything went well but...

When I checked out the contents, I realized that the difference between *empty web application* and *web application/bootstrap* is more than I expected. I got me a full blown MVC setup with views, controllers etc. And all the views are of course managed by Razor.

So my question is if it makes sense to skip Razor. If so, what's the alternative (goolearching gave me very little on this)?

I'm planning on going for Angular 2. Does it make sense to install Bootstrap at a later occasion? Or at all?

Comment: However it's primarily opinion based, it makes sense.

Comment: Hey Konrad, although this one is more of an opinion based question. Since you're using .NET, you want to at least utilize the basic MVC aspects. (Although when using Angular2, once the client takes over, all that "View" will be doing is loading the Angular2 app. One benefit of using .NET Core in this instance though, is that you can render Angular on the server with Universal (we've integrated it into .NET Core). So you can get even faster paints, great SEO, overall better performance.

Comment: We've made an Angular2 + ASP.NET Core starter here if you want to play around with it: https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal That will get you going in the right direction! Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is a static `index.html` in wwwroot, then you don't need it.

Must be something with yeoman installing the MVC by default, bootstrap by default (the NPM/Bower dependency) is just a bunch of javascript & css files.

If you need Controllers (for WebAPI/REST service calls, but not razor), you can use `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.1"` dependency rather than `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1"`. The later package also pulls all dependencies required for MVC including Razor. When using the `Mvc.Core` package you need to register it with `AddMvcCore()` in `ConfigureServiuces()` rather than `AddMvc()`.

If you need neither one (because your WebAPI is in a different project), then just remove the dependency. But you need `UseStaticFiles`/`UseDefaultFiles` instead but I think you already know that.

Also if you are working with Angular2 you may be interested in Microsofts [JavaScriptServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) package, which allows you to prerender the first request to the application server sided and the continue with client sided execution of it, speeding up the first laoding of the application as well as offering fallback routes.

Background: Angular2 doesn't use hash routes (example.com/myapp#/some/route) but uses hashless routes by default (example.com/myapp/some/route) which may cause an issue when you hit F5 in the browser while not in the app root url. The `routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute` call [here](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/dev/samples/angular/MusicStore/Startup.cs#L87) will just route all requests to the SPA apps root.

It uses MVC however. Not sure how you do it w/o MVC, probably you'll need to wait for the [URL Rewrite middleware](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/25/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1-preview-1/) which comes with ASP.NET Core 1.1.

Comment: Hehe, I had *AspNetCore.Mvc* and think that it's the Core's MVC. But nooo... We need to state *AspNetCore.Mvc.Core*. Not confusing. Not confusing at all...   :)

Comment: I can use *AddMvcCore()* instead of *AddMvc()* in the *ConfigureServices* method. However, I still only get to apply *UseMvc()* but not *UseMvcCore()* in the method *Configuration*. What am I missing? In [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4785) they also only talk about the *Add* in the services and not *Use* in the config. Typo?

Comment: Right my bad. I just remembered it on top of my head, since I knew one of the extension methods calls it. `AddMvcCore` is the right one and the `UseMvc` is already defined in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` package.

Comment: Hey, I'm starting to get a hang of it. Woohoo! Thanks to you, that is. In fact, I'm pretty often in Frankfurt, going south, just outside Stuttgart, so I insist on buying you a pizza next time I'm not in hurry.